# Recommended solutions to use PGP-compatible file encryption from a Java app running on Linux?

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp, pgp-desktop

I need to replace an existing application that, among other things, will need to encrypt/decrypt/sign messages and files in a manner compatible with PGP Desktop.

The new application is written in Java (JDK 1.6) and will run on Linux.

After surveying what's available, I see [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)  supports `OpenPGP`. Otherwise, JCE doesn't come with a PGP-compatible installation.

Calling the official command line client from PGP as an external process is something I would like to avoid as much as possible (and it costs thousands of Dollars).

Are there any other options or this is it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can call the GPG command-line client; it works like PGP, but doesn't cost thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 2):

[DidiSoft](http://www.didisoft.com/products/java-openpgp-library/) sells [OpenPGP Library for Java](http://www.didisoft.com/products/java-openpgp-library/).

Comment: any experience with it? My corporate overlords may not be pleased with a lesser-known company (even if product is fine) for all the usual reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @wish: Sorry, have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

[Cryptix](http://www.cryptix.org/) is another option, but it looks like the project was abandoned in 2005.  The Cryptix website recommends [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) instead.